# Python 'too many indices for array'

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I am using the following codes to visualize the predictions made by the decision tree function. However I get an error: IndexError: too many indices for array. I am new to python can someone advise on this error.

scatter_plot_data scatter plots the satellite data. A point in the plot is colored 'green' if vegetation is present and 'gray' otherwise.
input:
x_df - a DataFrame of size N x 2, each row is a location, each column is a coordinate
y_series - a Series of length N, each entry is either 0 (no vegetation) or 1 (vegetation)
ax - axis to plot on
returns:
ax - the axis with the scatter plot

Here is how x_train and y_train are created

[image]

```
def scatter_plot_data(x_df, y_series, ax):

# convert x_df and y_series into numpy arrays
    x = x_df.values
    y = y_series.values
    
    ax.scatter(x[y == 1, 0], x[y == 1, 1], alpha=0.2, c='green', label='vegetation')
    ax.scatter(x[y == 0, 0], x[y == 0, 1], alpha=0.2, c='gray', label='nonvegetation')
    ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_xlabel('Latitude')
    ax.set_ylabel('Longitude')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    return ax


    def plot_decision_boundary(x_df, y_series, model, ax, plot_boundary_only=False):
    
    # convert x_df and y_series into numpy arrays
    x = x_df.values
    y = y_series.values
    
    # Plot data
    if not plot_boundary_only:
        ax.scatter(x[y == 1, 0], x[y == 1, 1], alpha=0.2, c='green', label='vegetation')
        ax.scatter(x[y == 0, 0], x[y == 0, 1], alpha=0.2, c='gray', label='non-vegetation')
    
    # Create mesh
    interval = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    n = np.size(interval)
    x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(interval, interval)
    x1 = x1.reshape(-1, 1)
    x2 = x2.reshape(-1, 1)
    xx = np.concatenate((x1, x2), axis=1)
    
    # Predict on mesh points
    yy = model.predict(xx)    
    yy = yy.reshape((n, n))

    # Plot decision surface
    x1 = x1.reshape(n, n)
    x2 = x2.reshape(n, n)
    if not plot_boundary_only:
        ax.contourf(x1, x2, yy, alpha=0.1, cmap='Greens')
    ax.contour(x1, x2, yy, colors='black', linewidths=0.1)
    ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_xlabel('Latitude')
    ax.set_ylabel('Longitude')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    return ax
---------------------

    # set up to create two plots in the same image
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
    
    # visualize the data on the first plot (ax[0])
    scatter_plot_data(x_train, y_train, ax[0])
    ax[0].set_title('Training Data')
    
    #  plot the training data and decision tree boundary on the second plot (ax[1])
    plot_decision_boundary(x_train, y_train, tree, ax[1])
    ax[1].set_title('Decision Boundary on the Training Data')
    
    #  plot the test data and decision tree boundary on the third plot (ax[2])
    plot_decision_boundary(x_test, y_test, tree, ax[2])
    ax[2].set_title('Decision Boundary on the Test Data')
```

Finally the error is:

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-12-51049b1cd664> in <module>
          3 
          4 # visualize the data on the first plot (ax[0])
    ----> 5 scatter_plot_data(x_train, y_train, ax[0])
          6 ax[0].set_title('Training Data')
          7 
    
    <ipython-input-11-0719bb156aa2> in scatter_plot_data(x_df, y_series, ax)
         16     y = y_series.values
         17 
    ---> 18     ax.scatter(x[y == 1, 0], x[y == 1, 1], alpha=0.2, c='green', label='vegetation')
         19     ax.scatter(x[y == 0, 0], x[y == 0, 1], alpha=0.2, c='gray', label='nonvegetation')
         20     ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
    
    IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: An actual MCVE is always more useful than a code dump. You are responsible for your own basic debugging, including things like checking array dimensions, googling error messages, etc.

Comment: As the traceback makes clear, the error in this case is coming from the `x_train` and `y_train` arrays, and yet nowhere did you actually think to show us how those arrays are created.

Comment: I added an image with the first 5 lines of code that I used to create x_train and y_train

Comment: Array shape does not match somewhere, try inspecting `x` and `y` one line before error.

Comment: I am adding the link of the data set that I uploaded it into github, I am not sure if this is useful.However, the data set looks fine. [link]https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccnino83/Decision-tree-and-random-forest-classifiers/main/dataset_2.txt

Comment: I found my mistake on defining y =df[['veg']], I must use only single brackets. Thank you all for your assistance and your time. This is a great community and I feel very appreciated.